# OpenCV perspectiveTransform - applying the transformation matrix to 2D coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, linear-algebra

So I have generated a linear transformation matrix with perspectiveTransformation - M. I want to apply this matrix to coordinates on a 2D plane. However, I'm getting matricies back rather than coordinate vectors...

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

pts1 = np.float32([[228.31578, 163.70671],[449.21677, 163.16547],[136.58304, 412.18762],[530.23724, 420.48328]])
pts2 = np.float32([[100,100],[600.      ,   100      ],[100,500],[600,500]])
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

M = np.array([[ 6.83530783e+02,  1.03633028e+03, -1.33873998e+03],
       [ 5.04531603e+00,  2.80928089e+03, -9.08720768e+02],
       [ 2.99029665e-02,  2.78130789e+00,  1.00000000e+00]])

examplePoint = array([136.58304, 412.18762,   1.     ], dtype=float32)
```

when this matrix is applied to an image I get this - for some perspective on what the warping looks like:
[image: I do not care about the image itself]

the closest I have got to a respectable expected answer is this:

```py
examplePointTransposed = array([[136.58304],
       [412.18762],
       [  1.     ]], dtype=float32)

closestAnswer = np.dot(M, examplePointTransposed)

closestAnswer = array([[ 381.12108195],
       [1905.60543544],
       [   3.81121085]])
```

Hardly close to what I expect, This must be possible as I'm assuming the new coordinates for the image above using warpPerspective were calculated in a similar fashion.

any chance anyone could let me know where I am going wrong - I expect a coordinate system that maps to the warped image above

Comment: I've read that dividing the vector by 3 may work...

Comment: you want to apply a previously computed/known transform for a set of points? You can either use opencv's cv2.perspectiveTransform function (not getPerspectiveTransform) or you can use the multiplication M*[x,y,1] and divide the result by the z coordinate for each of your points.

Comment: Thanks Micka - that worked immediately! problem solved